# How to tell the g++ linker that there is an external add function implemented in x86-64 assembly (object file)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, x86-64, nasm, simd

I'm puzzled on why the linker doesn't link to the function in the object file.

I implemented a function in x86-64 assembly language and generated an object file via -f elf64. (Ubuntu is my target OS.)
The object file was successfully generated, but trying to compile my C++ project with the aforementioned object file results in the linker not finding my defined function (inside the object file).
Compilation was done like so:

```
g++ -W -Wall -pedantic -g -std=c++17 main.cpp SSE_Ubuntu_Tuple.cpp SSE_Ubuntu_Tuple.o -o test
```

```
#ifndef MATH_TUPLE_HPP
#define MATH_TUPLE_HPP

namespace Math
{
    struct Tuple
    {
        float components[4]; // x, y, z, w
        Tuple(float, float, float, float);
        Tuple operator+(Tuple&) const;
    }; // struct Tuple
} // namespace Math

#endif // MATH_TUPLE_HPP
```

```
section .text
global sse_ubuntu_tuple_add

; rdi = &x, rsi = &y

sse_ubuntu_tuple_add:
    movdqa xmm0, [rdi] ; xmm0 = *rdi
    addps xmm0, [rsi] ; *rdi + *rsi
    movdqa [rdi], xmm0 ; *rdi = xmm0
    ret
```

```
#include "Tuple.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

namespace Math
{
    extern void sse_ubuntu_tuple_add(float[4], float[4]);

    Tuple::Tuple(float t_x, float t_y, float t_z, float t_w) : components{t_x, t_y, t_z, t_w} {}
    Tuple Tuple::operator+(Tuple& t_rhs) const
    {
        float sum[4]{};
        constexpr int number_of_components = 4;
        std::copy(components, components + number_of_components, sum);
        sse_ubuntu_tuple_add(sum, t_rhs.components);
        return Tuple(sum[0], sum[1], sum[2], sum[3]);
    }
} // namespace Math
```

I expected an error free linkage and compilation.

Comment: I could be wrong but I *think* you can't compile & link from source `.cpp` and link in object files at the same time. You may have to first compile all your source files `.cpp` to object files and then link all the objects together in one command.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: "undefined reference to `Math::sse_ubuntu_tuple_add(float*, float*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: @Galik actually you can pass .cpp and .o to the same invocation of gcc or clang (I just tried it). That's not the problem here.

Comment: Tangential to your question, but this would be much easier (and more efficient) if you used [SSE intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_add_ps&expand=127) instead of assembly.

Comment: And if you do want to use separate functions for some weird reason, give them a function signature that will pass/return the data in an XMM register, not by pointer.  e.g. `__m128` args and return values in the x86-64 System V ABI.  Or even just the struct by value as a function arg (but not a return value, look at compiler-generated code; it would be expecting the struct as a return value split into 64-bit halves in XMM0 and XMM1).

Comment: Anyway, your current function only works with 16-byte aligned pointers, but you haven't told the compiler that.  It's mostly luck that it works, unless you knew the x86-64 SysV ABI specifies 16-byte alignment for all local / global arrays of 16 bytes and larger.  Use `alignas(16)` on the array member of your tuple.  Also, use `movaps` for FP loads.  `movdqa` is 1 byte longer, and on some uarches might cause a bypass delay to forward data from an integer-vector load to an FP `addps`.

Comment: I noticed a performance decrease.
My SSE: 110686737 ns; non-SSE: 103987236 ns.
@PeterCordes I will try to implement your suggestions and see how it unfolds.

Comment: @d03: performance decrease from what to what?  If your compile options don't include `-O3` or `-O2`, benchmarking is pointless.  The default `-O0` is not even trying to make efficient code.  Inlining `addps` with `_mm_add_ps()` is by far your best bet, don't mess around with separate asm for tiny functions.  Paul R is correct, I was just commenting to let you know that hand-written asm has correctness pitfalls too.  Even with args and return values in registers, call/return overhead for tiny functions will destroy performance, especially because all the XMM registers are call-clobbered.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had -O3 on. This is the C++ implementation: https://privatebin.net/?c3b3d42ac2fec739#5awnZiDQsx2qhfcWYJBqkdQNsdQXKDUU+uLCWZWvGi0=

This is the measurement setup: https://privatebin.net/?151d9a5d18be92a9#deiJm60C+UP07pRaPcKU0KurrlKeV2G1YA8xfT3FiSc=

Compilation via:

`g++ -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17 -o3  main.cpp Tuple.cpp -o testnosse` and

`g++ -W -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17 -o3 main.cpp SSE_Ubuntu_Tuple.cpp SSE_Ubuntu_Tuple.o -o testsse`

Comment: @PeterCordes So I am still not using intrinsic functions, but doing it like so:

`Tuple_SSE_Ubuntu.cpp`: https://privatebin.net/?0c91f508651fbe80#moc4YJt3p95GNObM00INo5+y4JF8tBQPcp+QeXiAaeY=

`Tuple_SSE_Ubuntu.asm`: https://privatebin.net/?2310e9c18db29bfb#iaLJZq7DY3TkftCyMp42ufEdpZL3f4Ddmnldqcf0jHI=

Resulted in: 122241524 ns (g++); 85486968 ns (NASM - w/ your helpful tips). :)

Comment: No, you have `-o3` which sets the output file name.  Capital `-O` sets the optimization level.  Anyway, your current design is still horrible: it makes a non-inline function call (clobbering all the XMM registers according to the x86-64 System V calling convention) for every `addps`, so the caller can't keep its *other* variables in registers.  And you still pass pointers as args, so the compiler has to store the args for your function to reload them!!  If you just wrote out a 4-iteration loop, gcc `-O3` would probably be able to auto-vectorize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193691/discussion-between-d03-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare `sse_ubuntu_tuple_add` as `extern "C"`:

```cpp
extern "C" void sse_ubuntu_tuple_add(float[4], float[4]);
```

Also, on some systems, in the assembly file you may need to create the symbol with a leading underscore: `_sse_ubuntu_tuple_add` .

Edit: apparently with ELF you do not need the leading underscore.

Comment: To expand on this answer, try `g++ -c SSE_Ubuntu_Tuple.cpp` and then use `nm` to inspect the symbol lists of both `.o` files: without `extern "C"` the name will be mangled (to allow overloading), which does not match the un-mangled name in your assembler listing.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for the clarification. I would also point out that mangling is not just for overloading: it also adds the namespace information (`Math::foo` is not the same as `foo` in C++).

Comment: @d03 Ah, well, I don't know what assembler you're using. Perhaps it adds the underscore automatically to global symbols.

Comment: @BrennanVincent I am using NASM.

Comment: @d03 I googled a bit and it turns out the underscore is not needed in ELF format.

Comment: The underscores are used in Windows COFF format/PE executables and Macho (MacOS) objects and executables.